# How do I configure SvelteKit to use Firebase Auth?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, svelte, sveltekit

I have it working with Firebase 8, but I can't seem to get Firebase 9 working...

Here is my firebaseConfig.js file:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyCAAngD7340_noXs7eesCfE9Y3cwqmiZhU',
    authDomain: 'svelte-todo-20f21.firebaseapp.com',
    projectId: 'svelte-todo-20f21',
    storageBucket: 'svelte-todo-20f21.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: '402466412167',
    appId: '1:402466412167:web:c739e7eb86fc5b6ac5ca22',
    measurementId: 'G-2N348J0NTE'
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
export const firestore = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

export default firebaseApp;
```

My auth.js file:

```
import { auth } from './firebaseConfig';
import { GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithPopup } from 'firebase/auth';

// Sign in with popup && Google as the provider
const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

export const googleSignIn = async () => {
    await signInWithPopup(auth, googleProvider)
        .then((user) => {
            console.log(user);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
};
```

And the index.svelte:

```
<script>
    import { googleSignIn } from '../auth';
</script>

<button on:click={() => googleSignIn()}>Sign In</button>
```

Seems easy enough but I'm getting this error that I can't resolve...
"500

The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/firebase_firestore.js?v=42dbe183' does not provide an export named 'getFirestore'

SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/firebase_firestore.js?v=42dbe183' does not provide an export named 'getFirestore'"

If it helps, someone suggested that I update my svelte.config.js file to the following...

```
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        // hydrate the <div id="svelte"> element in src/app.html
        target: '#svelte',
        vite: {
            ssr: {
                external: ['firebase']
            }
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Experiencing the same issue with Firestore.